# Closing a frame in Java and opening another one, with the swt library from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt

I'm currently making a reading app in Java, and this is [my main menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b5sZ.png).

What I want is that when I press the bottom button after selecting a book another window with the book opens. What I did now is a function that will open the other window while closing the one I'm currently in to free a little bit of memory.
I first close the current window after retrieving the necessary information from it (the index of the book) like this:

```
btnOuvrirLeLivre.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        int index = list.getSelectionIndex();
        LiseuseController controller = new LiseuseController(null, null);
        parent.dispose();
        controller.viewBookController(index);       
    }
});
```

(I'm using the MVC method for my project), parent is just the composite used to open the frame.

```
public void viewBookController(int index) {
    Display displayBook = new Display();
    Shell shellBook = new Shell(displayBook);
    shellBook.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    index += 250;
    LiseuseView lecture = new LiseuseView(shellBook, SWT.NONE, index);
    shellBook.pack();
    shellBook.open();
    while(!shellBook.isDisposed()) {
        if(!displayBook.readAndDispatch())
            displayBook.sleep();
    }
    displayBook.dispose();
}
```

The index is just the book's number in my database, everything should be fine but I get this error when I do this after pressing the button to open the book:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4875)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4790)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4761)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDisplay(Display.java:824)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:887)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:126)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:563)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:554)
at Controller.LiseuseController.viewBookController(LiseuseController.java:133)
at View.LiseuseHome$4.widgetSelected(LiseuseHome.java:81)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
at Controller.LiseuseController.viewController(LiseuseController.java:126)
at Main.Main.main(Main.java:59)
```

(LiseuseController.java:133) contains "Display displayBook = new Display();"

And (LiseuseController.java:126) contains

```
if(!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
```

This is from the other function used to open the first window.

I don't really understand what is causing this error and I can't just put one in "visible" and the other one "invisible" like if I'm using Jframe because the 2 windows are on 2 different .java files.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: You should only create a single `Display` when the application starts. Also you must do **all** UI operations on a single main thread, it looks like you are trying to use multiple threads for the UI. It is hard to say more from just bits of code.

Answer (score 0):

From the [API documentation](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Eclipse/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html) of `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display`

> Applications which are built with SWT will almost always require only
> a single display. In particular, some platforms which SWT supports
> will not allow more than one active display. In other words, some
> platforms do not support creating a new display if one already exists
> that has not been sent the dispose() message.

You should therefore adapt your application to use only one instance of `Display`. Since the class `LiceuseController` already manages opening the initial window and the supplementary window(s), it seems fitting for it to manage an instance of `Display` for both uses.

This instance should be created at the application's start, maintained by the `LiceuseController` class and finally disposed when the application shuts down.

---

Another problem is that none of the methods in `LiceuseController` actually returns. As you can see from the stack trace, `Display.readAndDispatch` from `LiseuseController.viewController` is still active when you are creating the new window. I guess you also want to reopen the original window when the supplementary window is closed. Opening and closing windows in this manner will, however, endlessly increase your call stack until you end up with a `StackOverflowException`.

Instead, the `LiceuseController` should be able to create windows without outside interference. Therefore, instead of *actively* calling a method in the controller class to open another window, the listener should only *tell* the controller what window it should open next when the current window was closed.

An example could look like

```
public enum WindowType {
    MAIN, BOOK, NONE
}

public class LiceuseController {

    Display display;
    WindowType nextToOpen = WindowType.MAIN;

    public LiceuseController() {
        display = new Display();
    }

    public void setNextToOpen(WindowType value) {
        nextToOpen = value;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (boolean run = true; run;) {
            switch(nextToOpen) {
            case MAIN:
                viewController();
                break;
            case BOOK:
                viewBookController();
                break;
            case NONE:
                run = false;
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("unexpected enum constant");
            }
        }
        /*
         * Depending on how you want to manage the instance of this class,
         * you could also extract this into a separate method.
         */
        display.dispose();
    }

    private void viewController() {
        // open main window using 'display'
    }

    private void viewBookController() {
        // open book window using 'display'
    }

}
```

so that a listener only needs to call `LiceuseController.setNextToOpen` and then close the current window. This will cause either `viewController` or `viewBookController` to return after which the loop will reenter and open the requested window. To shut down the application, call `setNextToOpen` with `WindowType.NONE`.